# Capture the POST or GET data of an iframe

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe on my webpage which is on a different domain. I know for security reasons in the browser it's not possible to access the content of that iframe using javascript, but can I detect any POSTs or GETs that take place as the user navigates from page to page of the iframe?

Comment: Please note I have modified the question to allow for GET's too.

Comment: You could use the `onload` event, but that won't allow you to retrieve any information about the requests - just that they took place

Comment: Thanks. On button click, can I use javascript to work out what url the iframe is on? The url will change as the user navigates, if I can capture that url I can get the data I need

Comment: You can't see the URL at all if it's cross-domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own both application you can teach them to communicate with `postMessage` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

With not much work you can create a simple method on iframe side that will tell what is its current `window.location`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Do you know if it's possible to use javascript to work out what url the iframe is on? The url will change as the user navigates, if I can capture that url I can get the data I need

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing you can do. It would be serious security issue if such data would be available to third parties.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, you can pass back some vars by printing them to parent.yourMethodToHandle() with some server side code. For example:

with php on the child page(in the iframe):

```
 $post_var = $_POST['var'];
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function(){parent.yourMethodToHandle('$post_var')});    </script>";
```

and the JS on your parent page(containing the iframe):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function yourMethodToHandle(post_var){//Do things}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is same domain a service worker might help you capture requests being made, intercept and return whatever you want.